# Button click triggering ListView GetView

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android

I have a `ListView` with an `Adapter` which uses a layout with 2 `Button` on it. One of those redirect to a page, the other performs an action.

The second `Button`, the one that performs an action, triggers the `ListView` to render all views again, which locks the UI for a while.

I don't have any calls to `NotifyDataSetChanged` or `NotifyDataSetInvalidated`, nor changing any data inside the adapter.

What can be the cause for the `GetView` to be triggered?

---

**EDIT:** Changed the way I was debugging the code and I must add the following:

- The `ListView` is inside a `LinearLayout`, and is set with `android:layout_weight=1`
- Below the `ListView` it's a `RelativeLayout` with some `TextView`'s that get updated with new values whenever the action of the second `Button` is performed

Comment: What is the action you're performing in the second button, could you post relevant code?

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: what does the second button do ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post any code here due to security issues. What I can say is that when that `Button` is clicked, I'll get is `Tag` and convert to a `Int32` var. After that, I perform some operations with the project classes, in which none of them access directly to any resource used in the `ListView`.

Comment: When the Listview item need to be rendered the 'GetView' should be triggered. You mean how to reduce the times of 'GetView' triggered ?